# awk assign command result to a variable

Tags: awk

I'm working on an awk script and am trying to get the result of a command assigned to a variable. I'm sure this is possible (command substitution?) but am not having success.

```
BEGIN {
    records_count = read_file_into_array("/usr/share/dict/web2", File)
    srand()
    printf "A random word: %s\n\n",File[int(rand()*records_count)]
    first=($(awk (File[int(rand()*records_count)]) ))
    print "New password: ",first
exit
}
```

The script correctly prints the 'random word' but I get nothing for 'New password'
Hoping someone here can shed some light?
Many thanks.

Comment: What exactly is that code snippet? I thought it was an awk fragment, but apparently it is not. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Yes it is an awk script. I'm reading a file of words and trying pick a random word, then assign the result to the variable 'first'.

Comment: read_file_into_array is a function I found to place the words in a file into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four things:

**First:** Each time you call `rand()`, you get a different number. Thus, the word extracted in the `printf` will be different from the word extracted in the `first=`

**Second:** Even if the first point weren't so, it is usually a good idea to call avoid calling a function multiple times if it can be avoided.

**Third:** The line

```
first=($(awk (File[int(rand()*records_count)]) ))
```

looks like a line from  shell script, not an `awk` script. Lose the `($(awk (` and the `) ))`, then it looks like `awk`.

**Fourth:** there is an `awk` exit command, but it is not needed in this instance.

Applying all that gives:

```c
BEGIN {
    records_count = read_file_into_array("/usr/share/dict/web2", File)
    srand()
    first=File[int(rand()*records_count)]
    printf "A random word: %s\n\n",first
    print "New password: ",first
}
```

Note that this would print the value of first twice, probably  not necessary.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the clear and correct response. Now I can move on.